# Extracting residual values from lavaan list matrices in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am using lavaan package and my intention is to get my model residuals as dataframes for further use. I run several models that have grouping variables. Here's the basic workflow:

```
require(lavaan)
df <- data.frame(
        y1 = sample(1:100),
        y2 = sample(1:100),
        x1 = sample(1:100),
        x2 = sample(1:100),
        x3 = sample(1:100),
        grpvar = sample(c("grp1","grp2"), 100, replace = T))
semModel <- list(length = 2)
semModel[1] <- 'y1 ~ c(a,b)*x1 + c(a,b)*x2'
semModel[2] <- 'y1 ~ c(a,b)*x1 
                y2 ~ c(a,b)*x2 + c(a,b)*x3'
funEstim <- function(model){
    sem(model, data = df, group = "grpvar", estimator = "MLM")}
fits <- lapply(semModel, funEstim)
residuals <- lapply(fits, function(x) resid(x, "obs"))
```

Now the resulting residuals object bugs me. It is a list of matrices that is nested few times. How do I get each of the matrices as a separate dataframe without any hardcoding? I don't want to unlist them as that would lose some information.

Comment: Looks like you have an editing / copy / paste error near the end of your code - the function does not have a closing brace.  Also, what do you mean by 'without any hardcoding'?

Comment: You are right. I fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list2env` along with `unlist` to make the `grp1`, `grp2`, `length.grp1`, and `length.grp2` directly available in the global environment.

```
list2env(unlist(residuals, recursive=FALSE), envir=.GlobalEnv)
ls()
#[1] "df"          "fits"        "funEstim"    "grp1"        "grp2"       
#[6] "length.grp1" "length.grp2" "residuals"   "semModel"
```

But they won't be data frames.  For that you could convert them to data frames before calling `list2env`:

```
df.list <- lapply(unlist(residuals, recursive=FALSE), data.frame)
list2env(df.list, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This works. However, I find a solution that I got from the lavaan Google group more convenient. lapply(residuals, function(x){lapply(x, data.frame)} does it.